# Does there exist a L-system for this Pierced Diamond Fractal?

Tags: computational-geometry, fractals

I'm just using L-systems. I do not know how to prove anything about them. I want to know whether it is possible to formulate an L-system for this Pierced Diamond Fractal. All my trials have failed.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, at least it seems to be possible to generated the shape with a graph directed iterated function system of similarities, which I believe (a reference would be appreciated, I couldn't find one in a quick internet search...) has equivalent expressive power to L-systems:

red rule:
[image: red rule]

blue rule:
[image: blue rule]

seed rule:
[image: seed rule]

result:
[image: result]

(sorry for the crude appearance, it's just a quick sketch in my https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2007-10-03_graphgrow.svg )