# expressivity of graph directed IFS and L-systems

Tags: reference-request, fractals

In my answer to [Does there exist a L-system for this Pierced Diamond Fractal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025689/does-there-exist-a-l-system-for-this-pierced-diamond-fractal) I asserted that graph directed iterated function systems of similarities have equivalent expressive power to L-systems.  Is this true?  A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: So-called "Parametric L-Systems", described in section 1.10 of *The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants*, can generate borderline fractals (as described in [this paper](https://marksmath.org/scholarship/PLSystemsPP.pdf)) that cannot be generated with digraph IFSs. Barring parameters, it makes perfect sense to me that L-Systems and digraph IFSs should be able to describe the same sets but I don't have a reference.